# How can I render existing view for output to PDF?

Tags: php, cakephp, tcpdf

I am using the TCPDF app in CakePHP as a vendor. I have everything setup according to the instructions. I am able to produce a valid PDF and it works great. Now I want to take the results of an HTML rendered view that already exists and create a PDF from it.

I set the HTML variable and use that in the view as:
`$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');`

Here is what I have tried and it renders a blank screen:

```
ob_start();
$this->render('results', 'pdf');
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$this->set('html', $data);
```

I have also tried:

```
$data = $this->results();
$this->set('html', $data);
```

But it only shows the PDF with the word `OBJECT` in it.

How can I render an existing view but have the output directed to the PDF?

Comment: do a `var_dump($data)` and see if your rendered html is stored somewhere in the object. Perhaps you'll have to do something like `$this->set('html', $data['somethinginternal'])`

Comment: I get `NULL` for the output. Nothing else. But I know the view outputs something when I visit it, it shows the page like it should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
ob_start();
....
ob_end_clean();
```

in the layout. For me it's too early to collect the data in the controller :)

Basically, I am using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to generate PDF content. It's really standalone and produces the html as it look in a modern browsers.

how I using it:
There is a pdf.ctp layout where I am using ob_start() ... ob_end_clean() in order to collect the content (incl the layout).

then I run wkhtmltopdf command with the output of the previously generated html, then read this file and print it in the browser.

You can see my /app/views/layouts/pdf.ctp [here](http://bin.cakephp.org/view/403747264). There are comments so you should understand it.

With this approach I could run my entire app in PDF :)

I haven't use the TCPDF recently so I don't know what he is doing. It could be similar :)

I've build a site with this approach: http://html-2-pdf.com so you can see this in action.

HTH

Comment: It turns out this is similar to the approach I have to take. It's VERY sloppy the way I did it (I think), but it is working. I had to set a variable in the existing view. If the variable is set to 'pdf', then I run the ob_start() and other commands necessary to generate the PDF. But I feel it makes the view very messy. I would prefer to have it generated from another location. Here's to my OCD!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Controller's afterFilter callback and output attributes. Here is an example:

```
function afterFilter(){
    $pdf->writeHTML($this->output, true, false, true, false, '');
}
```

Comment: This didn't work... but at the same time, this would run after EVERY method in the controller. That's not a side affect I want either. But thanks for taking a shot at trying to help.